# React Native - How to solve this error?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[This is my error.i have attach my error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rti1s.png)

```
static propTypes = {
onPushNotificationReceived: PropTypes.func.isRequired};componentDidMount() {  const onPushNotificationReceived = this.props.onPushNotificationReceived;}PushNotification.configure({onNotification(notification) {
    onPushNotificationReceived(notification);
        }
```

Comment: It's just a warning, you define `onPushNotificationReceived` as a property you want to pass to this component, but you pass nothing for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are not using propTypes properly. Please check this example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

you can find more informations [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)